# Python error while trying to run application on remote desktop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I am trying run the following script which will help me to open a SSH connection on a remote windows desktop and open an application in that remote desktop. I am getting an error when I read the error buffer:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('135.24.237.178',username = 'cyg_server',password = 'sandforce')

stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("C:\\Program Files\\Tensilica\\Xtensa    
OCD Daemon 9.0.3\\xt-ocd.exe")

stderr.readlines()
[u'bash: C:Program: command not found\n']

stdout.readlines()
[]
```

Seems I am not giving the path of the application I want to run on the remote PC correctly. Can anyone help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using cygwin to provide your SSH server on windows.  If so, you should reference your path through /cygdrive/c.  Try:

```
ssh.exec_command("/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Tensilica/Xtensa\ OCD\ Daemon\ 9.0.3/xt-ocd.exe")
```

Actually, you probably want a raw string as you'll want to pass the backslashes through to cygwin.. so... if the above doesn't work try...

ssh.exec_command(r"/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Tensilica/Xtensa\ OCD\ Daemon\ 9.0.3/xt-ocd.exe")

Comment: you are right, I am using cygwin to provide SSH server on wondows. Also, I tried with both of your codes. They worked definitely to a certain point. Though the application window of xt-ocd.exe did not pop up, but in the remote PC Task Manager -> Process es, I can find xt-ocd.exe running in the background every time I hit your ssh command from PyScripter. So, the process is starting but the application window is not opening. That remains the last thing.

Comment: You'll likely need to allow your sshd service to interact with the desktop.  I'll try and track down one of the servers that I have cygwin sshd running on and give you a bit more to go on.  But, as a general rule, services aren't allowed to interact with the desktop unless you explicitly allow it so not at all surprised you're not seeing the window open.

Comment: Tracked down one of the machines I have it running on and verified that if I change the service properties to allow it to interact with the desktop that it opens the application window for me.  (Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Services, CYGWIN ssd service, Logon Tab, Allow service to interact with desktop.  Restart the service).

Comment: I am close to the thing, again kudos to you. I followed your steps and say I am trying to open realvnc in the remote desktop with this command from my PC: ssh.exec_command("/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/RealVNC/VNC4/vncviewer.exe") ..immediately a message pops up in the remote PC: "Interactive Services Detection" and it says "The program might need information from you or your permission to complete a task"...I click on "View the message" and it opens a window but the display is not proper...its a blue screen with the Interactive Services Detection window in one corner asking me to "Return Now".

Comment: You're not by chance RDP'd in to the remote machine are you?  Because if you are, the desktop session you're attached to won't be the session that the service is trying to display its window in which could explain what is going on.

Comment: Yes I am RDPed to the remote machine through mstsc. I was trying to test the script functionality. If I cant RDP and check the script simultaneously, then I need to see how can I test that the script is actually working.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the space, like this:

```
ssh.exec_command("C:\\Program\ Files\\...
```

Comment: I tried this, it could not work: stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("C:\\Program\Files\\Tensilica\\Xtensa\OCD\Daemon\9.0.3\\xt-ocd.exe")
stderr.readlines()
[u'bash: C:ProgramFilesTensilicaXtensaOCDDaemon9.0.3xt-ocd.exe: command not found\n']

Comment: You're missing a space between Program and Files now, right?